# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'paresJSON'

Tags: jquery, json

i am using jQuery to get some JSON data from a php file.
my data is ut8 encoded and to decode it ( as i've understood, maybe im wrong) so it
won't show the \uXXX is the use parseJSON method.

my JSON data is :

```
({"4":{"id":"88","label":"\u00eb\u00e9\u00fa\u00e4 \u00e0'","parent_id":"1","level":"1","children":[{"id":"92","label":"\u00e4\u00e9\u00f1\u00e8\u00e5\u00f8\u00e9\u00e4","parent_id":"88","level":"2","children":[{"id":"96","label":"\u00ee\u00e9\u00fa\u00e5\u00ec\u00e5\u00e2\u00e9\u00e4 \u00f0\u00e5\u00f8\u00e3\u00e9\u00fa","parent_id":"92","level":"3","children":[]}]},{"id":"90","label":"\u00ee\u00fa\u00ee\u00e8\u00e9\u00f7\u00e4","parent_id":"88","level":"2","children":[{"id":"97","label":"\u00ee\u00f9\u00e5\u00e5\u00e0\u00e5\u00fa","parent_id":"90","level":"3","children":[{"id":"98","label":"\u00f0\u00e5\u00f1\u00e7\u00e0\u00e5\u00fa","parent_id":"97","level":"4","children":[]}]}]}]},"5":{"id":"89","label":"\u00eb\u00e9\u00fa\u00e4 \u00e1'","parent_id":"1","level":"1","children":[]},"6":{"id":"91","label":"\u00eb\u00e9\u00fa\u00e4 \u00e2'","parent_id":"1","level":"1","children":[{"id":"93","label":"\u00e4\u00e9\u00f1\u00e8\u00e5\u00f8\u00e9\u00e4","parent_id":"91","level":"2","children":[{"id":"94","label":"\u00e4\u00e9\u00f1\u00e8\u00e5\u00f8\u00e9\u00e4 \u00e9\u00e4\u00e5\u00e3\u00e9\u00fa","parent_id":"93","level":"3","children":[]},{"id":"95","label":"\u00e4\u00e9\u00f1\u00e8\u00e5\u00f8\u00e9\u00e4 \u00e9\u00e5\u00e5\u00f0\u00e9\u00fa","parent_id":"93","level":"3","children":[]}]}]}});
```

and my JS is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON(
    'some url.../getJSON.php?callback=?',
    function(data) {
        data = jQuery.paresJSON(data);

        $('#tree1').tree({
            data: data
        });

    }
);

});
```

this outputs nothing and shows me the error mentioned above.

any idea what have i done wrong?

Thanks in advance u guys,
Eric

Comment: your code uses `paresJSON` instead of `parseJSON`

Comment: @xbonez that seems like an answer

Comment: @3nigma: added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses `paresJSON` instead of `parseJSON`.

Fix that typo, and that should fix it.

Comment: That's the solution thanks man! though i now have an error from within the jQuery, "Cannot read property 'length' of null" in jquery.min.js:2, you don't happen to know anything about it right?

Comment: it seems you are attempting to access the length property of an object that has not been assigned. You might want to make another question for that